# Vertically center text in a box without knowing how many lines

Tags: html, css

This is driving me crazy I just don't understand why this piece of simple css to vertically center an element in a div doesn't work as expected.

this is the html:

```
<div class="header-a-wrapper" style="
    line-height: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
">
    <a href="/user/5659186348163072" class="right" style="
    background: blue;
    line-height: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
    height: 20px;
">medical salamander</a>

</div>
```

the inner element does not get centered vertically but I really think it should

here is an html with the two elements:
http://alephz.com/test.html

and this is the CRAZY part. here is a jsfiddle with the same html and over there it works! tested on the same chrome/win7!
http://jsfiddle.net/pkrsdqkb/

Comment: It is centered with `line-height: 48px;`. In the broken example [here](http://alephz.com/test.html) the element has `line-height: normal` which is removing the vertical centre.

Comment: @misterManSam both example have exactly the same css. The outer element has line-height: 48px while the inner one has normal

Comment: The difference is how jsfiddle.net interprets the HTML and CSS. The CSS is the same the result is just misleading :)

Comment: @MosheShaham The example is incorrect.  You only need line-height on the containing div, assuming it's containing text only.  Line-height for vertical centering DOES NOT WORK when you have more than one line of text - this is a completely different story and needs to be handle with faux tables or javascript

Comment: @misterManSam can you elaborate why i see this difference between the html and jsfiddle? i can't get it. when i inspect element, i see exactly the same html and css

Comment: @MosheShaham - As I already said, think of how many variables there are with jsfiddle. It displays your HTML and CSS within  an `<iframe>`. In some cases, the jsfiddle will be rendered differently. Relax! Regardless, I provided a simple fix below :)

Comment: @ntgCleaner I would gladly forget about it if it hadn't worked on jsfiddle perfectly! besides, the example is of one line, not two..

Comment: remove `display: inline-block;` from `<a>` tag

Comment: @MosheShaham, my "one like not two" was more of an FYI, not a correction.

Answer (score 0):

One option to play nicely with `vertical-align: middle` is to use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

- The wrapper gets `display: table` and `width: 100%`
- Wrap the links in a div which will act as a "table cell" with `display: table-cell`

`vertical-align: middle` will now work as you expect it to.

**Compatibility**: `display: table` is [good for IE 8 + and modern browsers everywhere.](http://caniuse.com/#search=display:%20table)

Example:

```css
.header-a-wrapper {
  background: red;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.vertical {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-a-wrapper">
  <div class="vertical">
    <a href="/user/5659186348163072" class="right">medical salamander</a>

    <a href="/user/5659186348163072" class="right">medical salamander</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Old answer

There is a lot of redundant CSS.

The vertical center is applied through: `line-height: 48px`.

Leave that on the wrapper and remove all the positioning CSS properties on `a.right`.

Example:

```css
.header-a-wrapper {
  line-height: 48px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-a-wrapper"> 
  <a href="/user/5659186348163072" class="right">medical salamander</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it works great, but it's not what i wanted since it does not take care of 2 lines of text

Answer (score 0):

Very weird, but if you want to solve it, you add to 'a':

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Remove

```
vertical-align: middle;
float: none;
```